# com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading pack file: uiskin.atlas

Tags: exception, libgdx

I try to use uiskin as a skin. json, atlas and png files are in the same folder.
It throw exception above.

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading pack file: uiskin.atlas
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas$TextureAtlasData.<init>(TextureAtlas.java:187)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.<init>(TextureAtlas.java:231)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.<init>(TextureAtlas.java:226)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.<init>(TextureAtlas.java:216)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:70)
```

Update: current code

```
Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));
nameText = new TextField("", skin);
```

Comment: Could you please add more Code/ any Code ?

Comment: I have added some snippets.

Comment: Your uiskin.atlas file is either missing, not in the same directory as the json and png files, or corrupted.

Comment: It is on the same place and I have downloaded it today from GitHub repo.

Comment: Same problem here. MY files were corrupt. Downloaded from Github via right mouse button->Download link. Resulted in corrupt files. For testing you could try to open the downloaded png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal(PATH_TO_JSON_FILE), new TextureAtlas(PATH_TO_PACK/ATLAS_FILE));
```